# How to configure DHCPD server to bind static IPv6 address by DUID?

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, dhcp-server

how can i configure the server to make static record DUID - IPv6 ?

For example i have such DHCPv6 request:

```
Client Identifier
    Option: Client Identifier (1)
    Length: 7
    Value: 31303030303133
    DUID: 31303030303133        # <--- this
    DUID Type: Unknown (12592)
```

And i want to bind some static IPv6 only for DUID 31303030303133;
How can i do this?

Comment: Which DHCP server software are you using?

Comment: @Sander Steffann, i am using 'isc-dhcpd-4.1.1-P1' on 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following configuration in your dhcpd6.conf:

```
host example {
  host-identifier option dhcp6.client-id 31:30:30:30:30:31:33;
  fixed-address6 2001:db8:111:222::333;
}
```

PS: that DUID looks weird. It is definitely not one of the [standard DUID types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xhtml#dhcpv6-parameters-6).

Comment: Thank you for the unswer. It kind of new device, which will include self serial number to DUID.
And one more question. Do i need to create subnet for 2001:db8:111:222::333 address ?

Comment: You need to create a /64 subnet on the LAN and you need a router that sends RAs to the LAN to provide subnet and routing information. That information is not part of DHCPv6